# Pass LAT LONG to Google Maps From CodeBehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-maps

I have tested the sample of Google Maps Java Example and it works fine, but how do I pass the Lat and Long from VB Code Behind?

This is the example:

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Map.aspx.vb"      Inherits="Learning.Map" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
    function initMap() {
        var uluru = { lat: 52.90560483, lng: -1.36920258 };             
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map
        });
    }
   </script>
   <style>
    #map {
        position: relative;
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
    }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>       
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ABCD&callback=initMap">
  </script>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have tried this in VB Code Behind:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "initMap", "lat: 52.90560483, lng: -1.36920258")

    End Sub
```

And adjusted the function to this:

```
    <script>
    function initMap(myvar) {            
        var uluru = myvar;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map
        });
    }
    </script>
```

The Only thing showing is a grey box. Can anyone help and tell me how I pass the Lat and Long to the function or even an easier way in code behind? Reason being, I'm going to call the Lat and Long from a SQLExpress Server.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assume you using `ASP.NET` without `MVC`

For the easiest way, you can put the **lat** and **lon** into variable in code behind, and pass them to hidden field (and get it from javascript or jquery) or just print it in the page

Code behind:

```
protected string _lat;
protected string _lng;

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    _lat = "52.90560483";
    _lng = "-1.36920258";

End Sub
```

Page:

```
<script>
function initMap(myvar) {            
    var uluru = { lat: <%= _lat %>, lng: <%= _lng %> };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
    });
}
</script>
```

The reason why your function failure because you pass the **lat** and **lng** together as a string, but google map need it as a object array.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the map refresh when my code behind _lat and _lng change?

Comment: @CodiMadison **_lat** and **_lng** stored in server, as http is stateless, you cannot notify client the changes.  But you may try to use ajax to check the change from time to time.